# Django passing objects to a new template

Tags: django

Lets say I have a list of objects being displayed in HTML like so:

```
{% for instance in object_info %}
    <li><a href="object">{{ instance.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

And when an object is clicked, a new template will be shown with details about the clicked object. As I understand, this can be done by passing the objects primary key in the url. Is there another way to solve this problem without putting any additional information in the urls (ie. just passing the parameters to the next view)?

Comment: You have to store the information somewhere. If you don't store it as part of the URL pattern (e.g. `/object/1/`), you can do it in the querystring (e.g. `object/?pk=1`), in `request.POST` (by submittimg a form), in the session, or in another cookie.